# How do I search in array and sum the corresponding values pertaining to the matching values in an array?

Tags: excel-formula, match, spreadsheet, sumifs

So, here is the pretend data where *columns B, C, D and E* have tags. Each of these column has tags which might match the tags in tags column. For example, the value in **B2** can be the same as the value in **E12**. The same can be observed across *columns B, C, D and E*. Then there's `w_score` *column F* where the score is alloted in accordance with the rank. Also, there's a *column G* which is named `unique_tag` which gives the unique value throughout the tag names in *columns B, C, D and E*.
The objective is to find out the sum of the `w_score` of the unique_tags in the column `p_score`.

Note: The unique_tag should be searched across the array where lies the tag names (*column B, C, D and E*) and sum of the corresponding `w_score` (*column F*) should be calculated in order to find the `p_score` (in *column H*).

Sample Example for `p_score` of unique_tag(`git`) `G1: 10+8.5+5+4.5= 28`
**Please refer the image below:**
[Dataframe of the pretend data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7klvm.png)

Comment: You might want to try sumif or sumproduct. The exact formula is going to be tricky.  Good luck!

Comment: Tried using sumif , it only considers the column range. That said it only returns the value if the match is made in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

SUMIF function doesn't search in an array (i.e. in multiple columns), although we can use the operator using SUMIF to aggregate the multiple columns search-in criteria. Simply, I got the desired output using `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$15, G2, $F$2:$F$15)+SUMIF($C$2:$C$15, G2, $F$2:$F$15)+SUMIF($D$2:$D$15, G2, $F$2:$F$15)+SUMIF($E$2:$E$15, G2, $F$2:$F$15)`